# C# WPF - Open a window and select a TabItem within that window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code to **open a window** on a button click:

```
private void LaunchSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 Settings = new Window1();
        Settings.Show();
    }
```

But how do I then **select a certain TabItem** within this newly opened window.

I know you can target a tab programmatically like so:

```
MyTabControl.SelectedItem = MyTabItem
```

Just not sure how to incorporate it into my first snippet of code. So basically, I want this all done in one call.

Answer (score 0):

`Window1` should keep a public property of the tab and of the TabBar so you can use it outside and set the tab as selected item for tab bar

This is the answer but you may post `Window1` so we can give more accurate code

In `Window1.cs` add

```
public var MyTabControl { get; set; }
public var MyTabItem { get; set; }
```

And in your external code do:

```
private void LaunchSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 Settings = new Window1();
    Settings.MyTabControl.SelectedItem = Settings.MyTabItem
    Settings.Show();
}
```

**Just remember to set values for the properties**