# Change Selected TabControl Programmatically - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl on my application and am not sure how to swap the tabs when users click on something other than the tab.

The initialization is stock:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I saw this question ([C# WPF - Open a window and select a TabItem within that window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583128/c-sharp-wpf-open-a-window-and-select-a-tabitem-within-that-window)), which seems to be a Windows Forms app.

I am not sure how to do the equivalent of `Window1 Settings = new Window1();` with `InitializeComponent();`

I have tried calling the TabControl by name, but there doesn't seem to be an option to set the active TabItem. I tried a few random things like below but couldn't get any response

```
SoftwareSelection.Items.MoveCurrentToLast();
SoftwareSelection.Items.MoveCurrentTo("Software");
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="SoftwareSelection" SelectionChanged="Software_SelectionChanged"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="245" Margin="160,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Width="346">
            <TabItem Header="Servers">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="-3,0,-9,0">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           Margin="10"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           Text="Things will go here"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                           Width="471" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Software">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,0,1,0">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                           Margin="10"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           Text="Stuff will go here"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                           Width="471" />

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

Comment: If you have time I recommend you have a look at this tutorial series. 
Especially around towards begining of video 5 and video 8. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JU9Ai0hpBUI&list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M&index=5

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TabControl.SelectedIndex` or `TabControl.SelectedItem` or `TabControl.SelectedValue`.

Comment: Or `TabItem.IsSelected`